# Differences between Tab, TabContext, Tablist, TabPanel, in React material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a hard time deciding when to use `TabPanel`, `Tabs`, `TabList`, and `TabContext` when working with [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/).

Is there a high-level overview of when to use each? It looks like all can... well make tabs.

Comment: Ahah that's funny, I am doing your bonus lesson on freeCodeCamp and I've had the same question

Comment: I'm glad you came to SO! You're doing the right thing googling stuff :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found much documentation, it seems that you can either use

```
<TabContext>
    <TabList>
        <Tab> </Tab>
        <Tab> </Tab>
        <Tab> </Tab>
    </TabList>
</TabContext>
```

OR

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab> </Tab>
    <Tab> </Tab>
    <Tab> </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

The former seems more customizable and perhaps less standard because it's in the `@mui/lab` library. The latter automatically wraps your Tabs in a `TabList` container, but you lose access to this container in-code, including the ability to add custom styles to it.

By the way @Patrick, I remember you from a Chainlink Hackathon a few years ago!